# Why my program is not switching display windows tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I want the program to switch display window, for example when I click on the button Next (the variable quit_button) I will see the text in label3 or the text in label2 "Hey There! Welcome to TutorialsPoint."
or "Find all the interesting Tutorials."
When I click on the. button Next nothing is happening. I tried to search for similar questions to mine but I didnt understand what I should add or change

```
import json
from time import sleep

import pywhatkit
import requests
from os import environ
import threading
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Radiobutton, StringVar, Frame
import requests
from googletrans import Translator

PARAMETERS = {
    "amount": 100,
    "type": "multiple"
}
FONT=("Courier",30)
radio_buttons_list = []
questions=[{"question":{"what is a logic bomb":["A computer virus","a piece of code intentionally inserted into a software"]},
            "answer":"2"}]
alphabet=[]
index = 0
tk = Tk()

greet = Frame(tk)
order = Frame(tk)

# Define a function for switching the frames
def change_to_greet():
   greet.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
   order.tkraise()

def change_to_order():
   order.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
   greet.tkraise()
def check_questions(i,answer,record):
    '''
    :type answer:str
    :param i:
    :param answer:
    :return:
    '''
    cnt=1
    valid=False
    if(str(answer).isalpha()):
        for i in range(len(alphabet)):
            if(alphabet[i]==str(answer).lower()):
                valid=True
                break
            cnt+=1
    if((str(answer)==questions[i]["answer"]) or (str(cnt)==questions[i]["answer"] and valid)):
        record+=1



def questions_generator()->None:
    translator = Translator()
    previous_string="{0}".format(questions[0]["question"].keys())
    return translator.translate(previous_string[len("dict_keys"):], src="en", dest="he").text

def radio_buttons(self):
    """To create four options (radio buttons)"""

    # initialize the list with an empty list of options
    choice_list = []

    # position of the first option
    y_pos = 220

    # adding the options to the list
    while len(choice_list) < 4:
        # setting the radio button properties
        radio_btn = Radiobutton(text="", variable="", value='', font=("ariel", 14))

        # adding the button to the list
        choice_list.append(radio_btn)

        # placing the button
        radio_btn.place(x=200, y=y_pos)

        # incrementing the y-axis position by 40
        y_pos += 40

    # return the radio buttons
    return choice_list
def increment(tk,index,question_data,selected_option):
     global radio_buttons_list
     global labal
     labal.config(text=question_data[index+1]["question"])

     answers=question_data[index]["incorrect_answers"]
     answers.append(question_data[index]["correct_answer"])
     for answer in range(len(radio_buttons_list)):
            radio_buttons_list[answer].config(text=answers[answer],
                                value=answers[answer], font=("ariel", 14))
 
     selected_option=None




def switch():
    global index
    if index%2!=0:
        change_to_greet()
    change_to_order()
def show_selected_option():
    print("Selected option:", selected_option.get())
def main():
  
    global user_input
    global image_label
    global output
    
    global tk
    tk.title("violetta QR_code_generator")
    tk.config(bg="#E8DFCA")
    cnt=0
    record=0
    response = requests.get(url="https://opentdb.com/api.php", params=PARAMETERS)
    question_data = response.json()["results"]
    global selected_option
    selected_option = StringVar()
    global index
    global labal
    while index in range(len(question_data)):
        labal = Label(tk, text=question_data[index]["question"], padx=300, pady=20, font=FONT)
        labal.pack(pady=15)  # pady display on the top of the window
        answers=question_data[index]["incorrect_answers"]
        answers.append(question_data[index]["correct_answer"])
        global radio_buttons_list
        for answer in range(len(answers)):
            radio_btn = Radiobutton(tk, text=answers[answer], variable=selected_option,
                                value=answers[answer], font=("ariel", 14))
            radio_btn.place(x=200, y=220)
            radio_buttons_list.append(radio_btn)
            radio_btn.pack()
      
        selected_option=None
        image_label = Label(tk, bg="#e6e6e6")
        image_label.pack()

        output = Label(tk, text="", bg="#F25252")
        output.pack(pady=15)
    
       
        label3 = Label(greet, text="Hey There! Welcome to TutorialsPoint.", foreground="green3")
        label3.pack(pady=20)

        label2 = Label(order, text="Find all the interesting Tutorials.", foreground="blue")
        label2.pack(pady=20)
        quit_button = Button(tk, text="Next",
                             command=switch(),
                             width=5, bg="red", fg="white", font=("ariel", 16, " bold"))
        quit_button.place(x=700, y=300)
        tk.mainloop()
 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You meant to write: `command=switch`.

Comment: You may find the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-my-buttons-command-executed-immediately-when-i-create-the-button-and-no) helpful.

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)